# How do I get file names in Fineuploader's onAllComplete event

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm trying to retrieve the filenames for the successfully uploaded files in the onAllComplete() event.  My code below returns "undefined" for the getName() call.  I'm not sure if the file name is in fact no longer defined at this point or if I'm attempting to access it incorrectly.  Any help will be much appreciated.  Thanks!

```
var uploader = $('#fine-uploader').fineUploader({
    ...
    callbacks: {
         onAllComplete: function(succeeded, failed) {
            if (failed.length > 0) {
                alert("Error: Some files were not uploaded");
            } else {
                if (succeeded.length > 0 ) {
                    alert("Success!");
                }
                this.reset();
            }
            for (var id in succeeded) {
                alert(this.getName(id))
            }
        },
        ...
    },
...
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `id` when the result of `getName(id)` is `undefined? Also, what does `this.getUploads()` return?

Comment: The values are always 0, 1, 2, etc. in order.   this.getUploads() returns "" (i.e., blank vs. undefined).

Comment: Duh, I figured it out.  The reset() call is clearing the values.  After I commented it out, I am now getting file names with this code.  Thanks for the help Ray!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The this.reset() is clearing the file names.